# Not sure what I'm doing wrong- dividing functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $g(x)=x+6$ and $h(x)=\frac{4}{x}$. Compute $\displaystyle\left(\frac{h}{g}\right)(5)$.

I've plugged $5$ in for $x$ but I keep coming up with $.07$ and thanks to webassign I know that is wrong. I'm sure I'm missing something basic but what is it?

Comment: It might just be a precision error. Have you tried $0.073$ or maybe $0.0727$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\frac hg)(x)=\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{4}{x(x+6)}$, so $(\frac hg)(5)=\frac{4}{5(5+6)}=\frac{4}{55}=0.0727$.... Leaving your answer as an exact fraction is better than giving a numerical approximation, unless the question asks otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

We have $h(x)=\frac{4}{x}$ and $g(x)=x+6$ so then $(\frac{h}{g})(x)=\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\frac{4}{x}}{x+6}=\frac{4}{x^2+6x}$. Evaluating at $x=5$ we have $\frac{4}{5^2+6(5)}=\frac{4}{55}$. Make sure to not round off or truncate. Online learning systems often don't do either...so just put in as many digits as you can.